# Convert data and time into a numeric number in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, long-integer, converters

I have a data & time format column which I would like to convert to the following format in Microsoft SQL Server: `yyyymmddhhmmss00000`

So for example if I have `2021-02-04 11:49:50` this will be converted to `2021020411495000000`.

Any one knows how to do it please?

Comment: Have a look at `CONVERT`, `REPLACE` and the concatenation operator (`+`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By converting the date to NVARCHAR once with format 112 and once with format 8 you can extract the numeric date and the time without milliseconds. After removing : from the time you can concat these two strings and convert them to bigint. Following an example:

```
DECLARE @d DATETIME = GETDATE()
SELECT CAST(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(8), @d, 112) + REPLACE(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(8), @d, 8), ':', '') + '00000' AS BIGINT)
```

Comment: Does it "need" to be an `nvarchar`? As the value only consists of numerical characters, why not use a `varchar` (which is half the size), or even better (as it's fixed width) a `char`?

Comment: @Larnu thanks for the hint. Yes, you are right - `char` and `varchar` work as well. Sorry I didn't think of this - we just used the `nvarchar` way in several of our queries and I just rememberd it

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `FORMAT` function:

```sql
SELECT FORMAT(myDate, 'yyyyMMddHHmmss00000')
```

Comment: thank you for this but you have to be careful when using this because it doesn't distinguish between AM and PM

Comment: Sorry needs to be uppercase HH have corrected